# how to pageinator link creation

Tags: php, mysql, rounding

I am trying to create a dynamic page links created based on the number of rows in a mysql table. I would like to display 10 results per page and wish to have the php script create links to additional pages.

So I was thinking of using the num_rows and dividing it by 10 however if I have 53 rows the return would be 5.3 where as I would need 6 pages and not 5. I am thinking of using the round function and looping it through a for I statement until $pages > $rows_rounded. And every 10 rows add a link to pages($i) Is this the best method to acheive this or there an alternative simpler route to take?

Comment: you would want to use ceil, not round. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of a for loop sounds like a good one, you would use something like:

```
$rows_rounded = ceil(mysql_num_rows($result) / 10);

for($x = 1; $x <= $rows_rounded; $x++){
    echo '<a href="/page-'.$x.'/'">Page '.$x.'</a>';
}
```

But you need to consider detecting the current page, so if, for example, the current page was 3, it might be a good idea to test for that in your for loop and if echoing the 3rd link maybe add some extra class to enable you to style it.

Comment: I think I would specify $x = $current_page; $x <= $rows_rounded; And then do another loop from $x = 1; $x <= $current_page;. the second loop would write page#1 to current page and first could write the loop from current page to last page. and i could style it within the loop and check if x = current_page and if so then style it otherwise print a normal link. I would _Get the values from gallery.php?page=3 and so forth...I think that should work...

Comment: actually the above is silly haha not thinking...yes I can check for the current page in the loop and style it...

Answer (score 1):

pagenator class I made. getCurrentPages() returns all the pages you should be displaying in an array. so if you are on page one, and you want to display a total of 9 pages, you would get an array 1-9. if you were on page 10 however, your would get back an array 6-14. if there are 20 total pages and you are on page 20, you would get back an array 11-20.

```
<?php

    class Lev_Pagenator {

        private $recordsPerPage;
        private $currentPage;
        private $numberOfTotalRecords;
        private $lastPage = null;

        public function __construct($current_page, $number_of_total_records, $records_per_page = 25) {
            $this->currentPage = $current_page;
            $this->numberOfTotalRecords = $number_of_total_records;
            $this->recordsPerPage = $records_per_page;
        }

        public function getCurrentStartIndex() {
            return ($this->currentPage - 1) * $this->recordsPerPage;
        }

        public function getCurrentPages($number_of_pages_to_display = 9) {
            $start_page = $this->currentPage - floor($number_of_pages_to_display / 2);
            if ($start_page < 1) $start_page = 1;
            $last_page = $this->getLastPage();
            $pages = array($start_page);
            for ($i = 1; $i < $number_of_pages_to_display; $i++) {
                $temp_page = $start_page + $i;
                if ($temp_page <= $last_page) {
                    $pages[] = $temp_page;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return $pages;
        }

        public function getPreviousPage() {
            if ($this->currentPage === 1) return false;
            return $this->currentPage - 1;
        }

        public function getNextPage() {
            if ($this->currentPage === $this->getLastPage) return false;
            return $this->currentPage + 1;
        }

        public function getLastPage() {
            if ($this->lastPage === null) $this->lastPage = ceil($this->numberOfTotalRecords / $this->recordsPerPage);
            return $this->lastPage;
        }
    }
?>
```

**EDIT (USAGE):**

```
<?php

   $pagenator = new Lev_Pagenator($current_page, $number_of_total_records, $records_per_page);
   $pages_array = $pagenator->getCurrentPages($number_of_pages_to_display);
?>
```

Comment: how would I use this? Do I need to specify any values? Or simply call the function? It sounds exactly what I need however I am not sure how to implement it...

Comment: @Drew never used classes before? well they are great, and you should read up right away! you can even make a class autoloader that will load the scripts that contain your classes only when you try to use the class. You will have to initialize an object using the class and give it a few inputs (arguments). See above edit for quick usage tips. Also note there are some other useful methods of the class like one to get what the currentStartIndex is, which you would use as the start record in your SQL statement.